# Maven error in MINGW Git bash: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Tags: windows, bash, maven, mingw

I'm aware of the fact that this issue has been discussed in several questions but no answer solved my specific issue.

I have installed Git bash and Maven and I'm trying to execute Maven with Git bash. It aborts with the mentioned error.

My system environment:

```
Windows 7
Git 2.13.3
Maven 3.5.0
```

The required user variables:

```
HOME=%HOMEPATH%
M3_HOME=%MAVEN_HOME%
MAVEN_HOME=path-with-no-blanks
Path=%MAVEN_HOME%\bin
```

Maven works fine on Windows command prompt and Cygwin. Only MINGW-based Git bash fails.

I examined the bash script `mvn` under: `C:\path\to\maven\bin`

By setting log outputs and by checking when `MAVEN_HOME` value gets lost I found out that it gets cleared by these statements (even `JAVA_HOME`):

```
# For MinGW, ensure paths are in Unix format before anything is touched !!!HERE MAVEN_HOME value is getting lost!!!
if $mingw ; then
  [ -n "$MAVEN_HOME" ] &&
    MAVEN_HOME=`(cd "$MAVEN_HOME"; pwd)`
  [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] &&
    JAVA_HOME=`(cd "$JAVA_HOME"; pwd)`
  # TODO classpath?
fi
```

On another Windows machine (different version of Maven and Git) the same lines are a bit different:

```
M2_HOME="`(cd "$MAVEN_HOME"; pwd)`"
```

instead of:

```
MAVEN_HOME=`(cd "$MAVEN_HOME"; pwd)`
```

First, I thought it's due to the kind of quotation characters. But the working Windows machine even runs well with the new script from my failing Windows machine. I also tried to install the old Git or an older Maven - nothing helps.

Why does the mentioned bash script line clears the `MAVEN_HOME` variable?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718502/maven-classworlds-launcher-launcher-error-in-git-for-windows. Are you using 32 or 64-bit Git?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't. My workaround was to modify the path in the bash script of Maven to the absolute path. One question: Do you use Comodo? I have the problem since I upgraded to the latest major version. But I cannot explain whether this is only coincidence or whether it has really something to do with this issue.

I'm using 64-bit Git.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm not using Comodo, but Maven with Git Bash had been working for me up until recently too. So there may be something external to Git Bash that's changed. I had done the same workaround, so will probably continue with that. Will let you know if I discover anything new.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the exact same error for a while until I realized that it was being cause by my antivirus (Comodo). Git bash would not work properly *even* if I had exited/disabled Comodo.

So if you have Comodo, try following these steps to fix the error (if you don't then maybe try performing something similar with whatever antivirus/firewall you are using):

1. Comodo->Settings->File Rating-> Add Folder (Git Folder). This ended up adding over 5000 trusted files (but it helped fix the issue).
2. Comodo->Settings->Advanced Protection->Miscellaneous-> and find the checkmark "Don't detect shellcode injections in...". I added the entire Git Folder to shellcode injections.
3. I set the git folder to "ignore" in Comodo->Settings->containment->"Auto-containment"

I'll add that I'm not sure if all of the steps are required, so feel free to perform them one by one and see which helps.

Comment: @mcknz if you don't have Comodo, is there a similar anti-malware solution with auto-sandboxing on your system?

Answer (score 1):

> Experiencing exactly the same problem on a Windows 7 machine. Happened overnight with no version change in git/mingw64, maven or java.

The first test you can consider is a PATH issue (the OP actually mention an incorrect `Path=%MAVEN_HOME%\bin`)

Use, for testing, a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51199066/6309) in a CMD session (so just limited to that session)

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

You can adapt the same idea in your `.bashrc`, if you want a similar $PATH in your bash session, by typing `bash` in the CMD with a simplified PATH.

*Then*; in that context, you can check again if the issue persists.