# IntelliJ GitLab. Push failed. Failed with error: Authentication failed

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitlab

Whenever I click push files to GitLab, first IDEA prompts me to enter login credentials.

[image]

This dialog window always pop up 3 times after clicking OK. login and password are correct. And after that I always get this error message:

[image]

Cannot even add remote in IntelliJ:

[image]

But I can "git add" and commit changes in IntelliJ.

Edit:
The solution is to use https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store. IntelliJ push now works after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is that your password include a special character that must be [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters).

Another is that you have the wrong credentials [cached in the Windows Credential Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679813/6309).

Regarding the remote, and its error message:

```
 Remote URL test failed: Authentication failed.
```

You can see in [`JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/plugins/git4idea/src/git4idea/remote/GitDefineRemoteDialog.java`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/6af34d4d38d21b9f654cde1fc91d710ab54a7707/plugins/git4idea/src/git4idea/remote/GitDefineRemoteDialog.java#L135-L141) that it does a [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote)

So double-check first what a `git ls-remote https://...` returns: it should pick your credentials in the credential helper.

---

As mentioned above, a **[credential manager](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)** issue was the cause.

```
git config credential.helper
```

IntelliJ should use the [IntelliJ Platform Credentials Store API](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/platform/credential-store).

Comment: There is no any special characters in my password. As for windows credential manager, there is no credential manager saved. I can git add and commit changes in IntelliJ but cannot push files to GitLab.

Comment: @DaryllDavidDagondon I have edited my answer. Did you try in command line a git ls-remote https://... as I now suggest in my revised answer? What version of Windows, IntelliJ and Git are you using? Are you using your gitlab.com username and password?

Comment: IntelliJ is 2016.3.7. git version 2.14.2.windows.3. Windows 7 Ultimate. Git ls-remote, git push and git pull works in Git Bash. git ls-remote returns 3 hexes. What is in git ls-remote?

Comment: @DaryllDavidDagondon `git ls-remote` is a way to check you can query a remote repo without having to clone it: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote

Comment: @DaryllDavidDagondon If it works in a bash, try to launch your IntelliJ from a CMD where you set first a simplified path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46777994/6309

Comment: It now works after I followed https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

Comment: @DaryllDavidDagondon Great. A credential helper issue as I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Git add and git commit are local operations, they need no password. A password is required for operations with remotes only - push, pull, ls-remote.

Does it work if you try pushing from the command line?

Also, it is worth checking [the logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) to find the exact error reason, This could be not only a wrong password but some other underlying error.

Comment: I can push in Git Bash. But a push in IntelliJ won't.

Comment: It now works after I followed https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store. IntelliJ push now works after that.