# running a simple ls command with subprocess and git bash

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, git-bash

I am trying to call a git bash shell command from inside Windows operating system. Following is my code snippet. Can anyone please tell me, what I am doing wrong?

```
    git_bash_path = WindowsPath(r"c:\Users\abcd\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\git-bash.exe")
    command = "ls"
    subprocess.call([str(git_bash_path), command])
```

After running, the python script, it opens a bash window with the title in the window - `/usr/bin/bash --login -i ls` and in the git bash window the error is `bash:/usr/bin/ls`: cannot execute binary file.

I also tried -

```
    subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, executable=str(git_bash_path))
```

but the error is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should use the `-c` parameter:

```
bashCommand = "ls"
output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bashCommand])
```

[Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) comes with a `bash.exe`. It is [is in the `%PATH%`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734053/6309), that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, in case %PATH% does not have bash.exe, do

```
command = fr'"%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\bash.exe" -c "echo hello"'
r = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

This assumes that Git Bash is installed in default Program Files location.